# Ansible is using the Vagrant IdentitiyFile and not the one for the user on the box?

Tags: vagrant, ansible

When running commands with `ansible` on a vagrant box, it is using the identity file located here:

```
IdentityFile="/Users/me/.vagrant.d/boxes/ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-trusty32/0/virtualbox/vagrant_private_key"
```

Instead of the file on the box: `~/.ssh/id_rsa`

What can I do to fix this? This is my task by the way:

```
---
  - name: Fetch the Htt Database
    run_once: true
    delegate_to: 543.933.824.210
    remote_user: ubuntu
    become_user: root
    fetch: src=/home/ubuntu/file.sql.gz dest=/tmp/file.sql.bz fail_on_missing=yes
```

Answer (score 0):

By-default vagrant use `insecure_private_key` to login `vagrant` user and that is not secure because every one know that `key` so if you want to use your `ssh key` then you can modify your `Vagrantfile` by adding lines

```
config.ssh.username = "username"
config.ssh.private_key_path = "fullpath-of-ssh-private-key"
config.ssh.insert_key = false
```

According to vagrant Documentation

> config.ssh.insert_key - If true, Vagrant will automatically insert an
>   keypair to use for SSH, replacing the default Vagrant's insecure key
>   inside the machine if detected. By default, this is true.
>
> This only has an effect if you don't already use private keys for
>   authentication or if you are relying on the default insecure key. If
>   you don't have to take care about security in your project and want to
>   keep using the default insecure key, set this to false.

also make sure you have `public-key` of your `private-key` in guest vm at `/home/username/.ssh`

For info you can use [vagrant Documentation](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html)

Comment: is that path on local or on the vagrant box?

Comment: local host system. we alway keep public in guest vm (virtualbox) in that user home directory /home/user/.ssh and private key in host system.